# Find(System.Object[]) cannot be called with instance of type .ObjectQuery

Tags: c#, api, controller, get

I'm trying to get the user from the database.

```
// GET: api/Pedido
public IQueryable<PedidoDTO> GetPedido()
{
    var pedido = from p in db.Pedido
                 select new PedidoDTO()
                 { 
                     Id = p.Id.ToString(),
                     NomeEmpregado = db.Users.Find(p.ApplicationUserId).PrimeiroNome,

                     DataPedido = p.DataHoraPedido
                 };
```

At the "NomeEmpregado = db.Users.Find(p.ApplicationUserId).PrimeiroNome,"

When i do a Get an error occurs :

Message=Method 'apiRestaurante4.Models.ApplicationUser Find(System.Object[])' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet`1[apiRestaurante4.Models.ApplicationUser]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[apiRestaurante4.Models.ApplicationUser]'
  Source=System.Core

The class Pedido :

```
public class Pedido
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]        
    public virtual ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }

    public int? Mesa { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataHoraPedido { get; set; }
    public List<ItemMenu> Items { get; set; }
}

public class PedidoDTO
{

    public string Id { get;set; }
    public string NomeEmpregado { get; set; }
    // Nome do empregado que fez o pedido
    public DateTime DataPedido { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ApplicationUser Utilizador { get; set; }

}
```

When i comment the find line the code works perfectly.
I want to return the user but all my attempts failed

Also tried to instead getting a String with the name of the user, tried to get the user with no success.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).